# Find the probability that a duel ends after the $n^{th}$ round of shots.

Tags: probability

$A$ and $B$ are involved in a duel. The rules of the duel are that they are to pick up their guns and shoot at each other simultaneously. If one or both are hit, then the duel is over. If both shots miss, then they repeat the process. Suppose that the results of the shots are independent and that each shot of $A$ will hit $B$ with probability $p_A$, and each shot of $B$ will hit $A$ with probability $p_B$.

What is

(a) the probability that A is not hit?
(b) the probability that both duelists are hit?
(c) the probability that the duel ends after the n-th round of shots?
(d) the conditional probability that the duel ends after the n-th round of shots given that A is not hit?
(e) the conditional probability that the duel ends after the n-th round of shots given that both duelists are hit?

I know how to do (a) and (b), but I need help with (c) and I think that if I know $c$ I will also know how to do (d) and (e).

For (a) I got the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((1-p_A)(1-p_B))^{n-1}p_A(1-p_B),$$ after using the sum of an infinite geometric series I get

$$\frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}$$

and for (b) I got the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((1-pA)(1-pB))^{n-1}p_Ap_B,$$ after using the sum of an infinite geometric series I get $$\frac{p_Ap_B}{1-(1-p_A)(1-p_B)}.$$

Is the answer to part (c) simply: is the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((1-p_A)(1-p_B))^{n-1},$$  correct to express the answer to a probability as a sum?

Comment: Hint: for c) in order for the duel to end in exactly the $n^{th}$ round you need both duelists to miss for $n-1$ rounds and then you need them not to both miss on the $n^{th}$.  Thus, if $q$ is the probability that they both miss on a particular round the answer is $q^{n-1}(1-q)$.

Comment: the question says that if one or both of the duelest are hit the duel is over, then why do I need them not to both miss on the n-th when it can end if only one hits and the other misses?

Comment: The condition "the players don't both miss" includes 3 events:  both hit, A alone hits, B alone hits.  I phrased it the way I did because it is easier to get the probability by subtraction.  If you prefer you can add the probability of the three events.  Same result.

Comment: after rereading it a few times I realized what you meant, so for d the answer would be both duelest miss for n-1 rounds and then A makes his shot but B misses his shot which ends the game: ((1−pA)(1−pB))^(n−1) (pA)(1-pB)

Comment: Exactly.  You've got it.

Comment: since part D is conditional probability given that A is not hit shouldnt the answer be q^(n-1) because the we given that duel ends with only B getting hit so we shouldnt have to calculate the probability for that like I did?

Comment: You are correct that the "conditional" part needs to be taken into account. But $P(game\; ends|A \;survives)=\frac {P(game\; ends\cap A survives)}{P(A\; survives)}$.  But this is $\frac {q^{n-1}P_A(1-P_B)}{1-P_B}=q^{n-1}P_A$.